# Dynamic dropdown is not making conditional statements

Tags: jquery, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I have this dropdown which gets data dynamically from database and this is how I get the info:

```
function buscarHist(fgshgdjhgfgffjtfj){

    $('.divHist').show();
    $('#down').html('');
    $.getJSON("./php/obtenerDatos.php",{IDA:fgshgdjhgfgffjtfj}, function(data){
    var enca =  Object.keys(data[0]);
    // console.log(enca);
      $.each(enca,function(i,item){
        console.log(enca);
       // $('#catalogos').append(item)
        $('#down').append('<option value ="' + data[0][item] + '" > '+ item +' </option>')
   
       // console.log(item)
      });    
    });
```

Inside ./php/obtenerDatos.php is this piece of code

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../../includes/dbconnect.php');
$Q = new Util();
$BD = new Util();
$BUSQUEDA = array();
$ESC = isset($_SESSION['ESCUELA']) ? $_SESSION['ESCUELA'] : "";
$USR = isset($_SESSION['login_user']) ? $_SESSION['login_user'] : "";

$contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';
if($contentType === "application/json") {
  $content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
  $PARAMS = json_decode($content, FALSE);
  
  if(is_object($PARAMS)) {
  }
}else{
 // $OPC = isset($_GET['OPC']) ? $_GET['OPC'] ;

//  if($OPC == "1"){
    $ID_USR = $_GET['IDA'];

    $Q = $BD->consulta("
    
    SELECT * FROM DATOS_BASICOS WHERE ID_USR = '$ID_USR'
");

   // $Q = $BD->consulta("CALL SP_SMS_ALUMNOS(1, '$CURP');");
    while($O = mysqli_fetch_object($Q)){
     array_push($BUSQUEDA, $O);
    }
    ECHO json_encode($BUSQUEDA,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    if($BD->con->error != '')ECHO $BD->con->error;
 // }

}
```

Everything is working fine but I must add some list to another dependent dropdown and I'm using switch statements which is not working

this is my code and for some reason its not making any changes this is my desired result but obviously I wont use hardcoded option inside value and labels that's what I'm getting from database

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var AFIRMACIONES = [{
      display: "NO",
      value: "0"
    },
    {
      display: "SI",
      value: "1"
    }
  ];

  var AFIRMACIONES2 = [{
      display: "SI",
      value: "1"
    },
    {
      display: "NO",
      value: "0"
    }
  ];

  var AFIRMACIONES3 = [{
      display: "CASADO",
      value: "1"
    },
    {
      display: "SOLTERO",
      value: "2"
    },
    {
      display: "VIUDO",
      value: "3"
    }
  ];

  // $(document).ready(function() {
  getSelectData($("#down"));
  $('#txtnombre').val($('#child_selection').children(':selected').text())
  // });

  $("#down").change(function() {
    getSelectData($(this));
  });

  function getSelectData(el) {
    console.clear();
    var $option = el.find("option:selected");
    var text = $option.text();
    console.log(text);

    switch (text) {
      case "PESO":
        list(AFIRMACIONES);
        break;
      case "ZURDO":
        list(AFIRMACIONES2);
        break;
      case "EDO_CIVIL":
        list(AFIRMACIONES3);
        break;

      default:
        $("#child_selection").html("");
        break;
    }
  }

  function list(array_list) {
    console.log(array_list);
    $("#child_selection").html("");
    $(array_list).each(function(i) {
      $("#child_selection").append(
        '<option value="' + array_list[i].value + '">' + array_list[i].display + "</option>"
      );
    });
    $('#txtnombre').val($('#child_selection').children(':selected').text())
  }

  $('#child_selection').change(function() {
    $('#txtnombre').val($(this).children(':selected').text())

    //$("#txtnombre").hide();

    // }

  })
});



This is an example of the desired result but it seems its only working when I put the values and labels on my dropdown and as I said I must return this info from my database .. do am I missing something?
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="down">
  <option value="1">PESO</option>
  <option value="2">ZURDO</option>
  <option value="3">EDO_CIVIL</option>
</select>

<select name="child_selection" id="child_selection">
</select>

<input id="txtnombre" type="text" class="form-control autofocus form-control-round F1" placeholder="SIN INFORMACION" />
<input id="txtnombre2" type="text" style="visibility:hidden" class="form-control autofocus form-control-round F1" placeholder="SIN INFORMACION" />
```

This is my HTML  the real code please note the snippet above is only as REFERENCE because there I don't use any database

```
  </div>
                <div class="card-block">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-responsive-sm table-striped table-xs table-hover">
                            <thead>
                            </thead>                                    
                         <select name="down" id="down"  > 
                           
                         </select>
                     <select name="child_selection" id="child_selection">
                          </select>
                        
                         <input id="txtnombre" type="text" class="form-control autofocus form-control-round F1" placeholder="SIN INFORMACION"/>
                         <input id="txtnombre2" type="text"  style="visibility:hidden" class="form-control autofocus form-control-round F1" placeholder="SIN INFORMACION"/>
                           </script>

                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <button id="btnGuardar" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-primary btn-block"><i class="ti ti-save"></i> Guardar</button>
                            </div>

                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and this is my JS FILE :

```
$('#down').change(function(){
 //$('#txtnombre').val($(this).val()) 
 $('#txtnombre').val($(this).val());
// var mivalor = $('#txtnombre').val() 

})
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 
  var AFIRMACIONES = [
    {display: "NO", value: "0" }, 
    {display: "SI", value: "1" }
   
  ];
    
  var AFIRMACIONES2 = [
    {display: "SI", value: "1" }, 
    {display: "NO", value: "0" }
   ];

   var AFIRMACIONES3 = [
    {display: "SOLTERO(A)", value: "1" }, 
    {display: "CASADO", value: "2" },
    {display: "UNION LIBRE", value: "3" },
   ];

  // $(document).ready(function() {
  getSelectData($("#down2"));
  // });

  $("#down2").change(function() {
    getSelectData($(this));
  });

  function getSelectData(el) {
    console.clear();
    var $option = el.find("option:selected");
    var text = $option.text();
    console.log(text);
    switch (text) {
      case "PESO":
        list(AFIRMACIONES);
        break;
      case "ZURDO":
        list(AFIRMACIONES2);
        break;

        case "EDO_CIVIL":
          list(AFIRMACIONES3);
          break;
      default:
        $("#child_selection").html("");
        break;
    }

  }

  function list(array_list) {

    $("#child_selection").html("");
    $(array_list).each(function(i) {
      $("#child_selection").append(
        '<option value="' + array_list[i].value + '">' + array_list[i].display + "</option>"
      );
    });
  }
});


$(function() {
  var 
  jqDdl = $('#down'),
  onChange = function(event) {
      if ($(this).val() === '1') {
          $('#txtnombre').hide();
          $('#txtnombre').focus().select();
      }       
      else if ($(this).val() === '0') {
        $('#txtnombre').hide();
        $('#txtnombre').focus().select();
      }
      
      else {
          $('#txtnombre').show();
      }
  };
  onChange.apply(jqDdl.get(0)); 
  jqDdl.change(onChange);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `$(array_list).each(function(i) ...)` is used when `array_list` is a jQuery selector. But `array_list` is an array of object, not a selector. The correct syntax to iterate over an array is `$.each(array_list, function(i) ...)`.

Also, the second argument to the iteration function is the array element, so instead of referring to `array_list[i]` in the callback, you can add another parameter and use that. And jQuery also sets `this` to the element, so you can use that.

Comment: the issue is not there because when I use hardcoded dropdown is working indeed i only want to know why is not making any changes and it doesnt recognize the conditional values on Switch

Comment: that's an example of what i want actually my issue comes when instead of using the dropdown i use there on the snipet I use the one where im getting the data from database  its not the same only using   <select name="down" id="down"  > 
 </select> ...  instead the one i used on the example